# Android Application penetration testing

Tags: penetration-test, android

Have problem intercepting HTTPS requests of android application.certificates in android are kept under **/system/etc/security/cacerts/** which is different from its previos version of os in **cacerts.bks** format.Also tried to add certificates from device but it did not work.Any help to intercept the proxy.Android vesion ICS 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [BURP which will create a fake SSL certificate](http://forum.portswigger.net/index.cgi?board=how&action=display&thread=10) that the application will probably accept.  If the application is using certificate pinning,  then it becomes more difficult,  you'll have to patch the application in quesiton.